# HTC One S won't boot after battery fully drained

Tags: battery, boot, htc-one-s

Today the battery of my HTC One S got completely empty and when trying to reboot it's just stuck on the splash screen.

I am rooted and have Trickdroid 8.1 installed. This is an 4.0.4 ICS ROM.

I've already wiped cache+dalvik and reflashed the boot.img to no avail...

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too bad Android SE is not as active as other SE sites, just did a nandroid restore from when I just installed the ROM and so far I haven't set up titanium backup. Well that'll teach me... At least it boots again.